# Javascript array not working ?? confused

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Anybody got any clue why this won't work with more than 1 date...

it only takes the first date in the array...

```
var unavailableDates = ["10-6-2011","13-6-2011"];

function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == 0) {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
    } else {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 0 && day != 2 && day != 3 && day != 4 && day != 6)];
    }
}
```

see full example below

http://offline.raileisure.com/lee.php

Thanks in advance

Lee

Comment: You really should have posted the actual code that tries to use the array. Posting nothing more than a link to your site will not be helpful to Stackoverflow readers a year from now.

Comment: Try providing some additional details on how exactly it fails.

Comment: @Greg the first date is disabled but the others in the array don't disable, its as if the code isn't reading anything after the first value in the array

Comment: Having your dates in an ambiguous format is almost always a bad idea. If you're going to use date strings, it's almost always best to stick with yyyy-mm-dd format. Also, whatever format you use, avoid single-digit days or months, as these can throw things out as well: use 06 rather than just 6

Comment: Define "this won't work"

Comment: the var unavailableDates is declared as private,not accessed in unavailable function,remove the 'var' in you declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery.inArray returns the index of the item found, ie, when it matches the second value, it is returning 1, not the 0 you test for.

You should change your test to be `>= 0` rather than `== 0` when you do

```
if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == 0) { ...
```

Comment: Yea, we've actually been telling you this for a while, Lee. Please follow advice given in comments. Still, +1 this is the most concise answer that solves the problem _and_ explains it.

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't work because you're interpreting the return value of "$.inArray()" incorrectly. The function returns **-1** when the search target cannot be found, and the index in the array when it can. Thus, when it returns **0**, that means it **did** find what the code was looking for.

A cute trick — for those who like cute tricks — for checking the return value from functions like "$.inArray()" is to apply the "~" operator:

```
if (~$.inArray(needle, haystack)) {
  // found it
}
else {
  // did not find it
}
```

The "~" operator forms the bitwise complement (or "1's complement") of its argument.  Because "~-1" is 0, and "~n" is non-zero for any other integer, it effectively converts the return value to a "truthy/falsy" value appropriately.  Don't use it if you don't like cute tricks :-)

Also, that "dmy" variable used in a couple functions should be declared in each one with the `var` keyword.

Comment: Its correct that when it finds the date it needs to return false and disable that date

Comment: +1 though you forgot the obligatory link to the [manual page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) that the OP should already have been reading merely from the fact that he's used the function!

Comment: @Lee: `$.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) != -1` then. You only had it for `== 0` (i.e. the first element).

Comment: @Lee: The lesson we're all learning here, I hope, is that your code is hard to read. It's not obvious what it does.

Comment: good work : )  in pure javascript: function inArrayOrStr (o, v) {
  return ~o.indexOf(v);
 }

Answer (score 1):

Is it reading it in as mm-dd-yyyy?

If so - then `13-6-2011` would not be a valid date.

*Edit* Okay - looking at your page; clearly not since 10th June is not available as expected.

I deleted the answer but where dates are concerned I think this is a valuable thing to remember (e.g. on a US client presumably I'd be right?) so I undeleted it.

I'll get rid of it again though if the community feels I should.

Comment: No the first date is working fine and its in the right format

Comment: +1 because this seems very plausible -- having your dates in an ambiguous format is almost always a bad idea. If you're going to use date strings, it's almost always best to stick with `yyyy-mm-dd` format. Also, whatever format you use, avoid single-digit days or months, as these can throw things out as well: use `06` rather than just `6`.

Comment: -1 Locales have nothing to do with it. He's not reading anything in to a date parser; he's building strings in a fixed format and comparing them.

Comment: @Tomalak - good point.

That's reason enough for me to delete then

Comment: @Andras: Yea, either that or let it live and collect downvotes. :) Which is not necessarily a bad thing. Every question needs downvoted wrong answers to contrast the upvoted right ones.

Comment: @Tomalak - I agree with that definitely.  Not sure I want one of my answers to be a bin for downvotes though! ...[thinks] although I would then collect the peer-pressure badge :)

Comment: @Tomalak - true. Although I reckon if it were, the Skeet would be the end-boss.  Fearsome.

Comment: @Andras: +1 for the subjunctive mood

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
in pure javascript:
I made ​​some modifications to make your code faster

```
function inArrayOrStr (o, v) {
    return ~o.indexOf(v);
}

unavailableDates = ["10-6-2011","13-6-2011"];

function unavailable(date) {
    var dmy = [date.getDate() ,(date.getMonth() + 1) , date.getFullYear()].join("-");
    if (inArrayOrStr(unavailableDates, dmy) {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
    } else {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [day > 7];
    }
}
```